# How to know when a Gtk Window is fully shown?

Tags: gtk

I'd like to know which signal is emitted when a `Gtk.Window` is fully shown, with fully shown I mean the window itself is shown and its widgets too.

I tried several signals:

- show
- realize
- visibility-notify-event
- set_focus

but none of them works properly.

The only interesting answer I found on the web is [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1456787).

Comment: If you need the proper dimensions (width, height) too, the only signal that worked for me was `size_allocate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect a callback after the [GtkWidget::draw](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-draw) signal (previously called `expose` in GTK+2).

**Addendum**

There is other stuff that comes into play: [double buffering](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-drawing-model.html#double-buffering), [client-side windows](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk-migrating-ClientSideWindows.html) and (why not?) the fact that a widget can defer its drawing in an idle callback.

If you want to know when your main window appears the first time, it is far easier (and saner) add a [`g_idle_add`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) after your `show_all` call.

Comment: I've just tried, but the draw signal is emitted when the window is showed, but before its widgets are showed

Comment: Have you tried `g_signal_connect_after` instead of `g_signal_connect` ?

Comment: @liberforce: this is still not enough. For example double buffering wraps the draw signal between `gdk_window_begin_paint_region` and `gdk_window_end_paint` calls to avoid flickering.

Comment: The `g_idle_add` solution seems to work, but I think it is not deterministic. In fact I think it works because up to when the window is fully shown, Gtk is busy and doesn't execute the function passed as argument to `g_idle_add`. But I don't know if this behavior is deterministic.

Comment: @robbo: it is deterministic. You have one process, one thread and one event loop: how cannot be deterministic? The idle function has been implemented to do exactly what you described, that is being called after any other pending event with higher priority is executed. As you can see from http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#G-PRIORITY-DEFAULT-IDLE:CAPS event handlers have higher priority.

Comment: @ntd: This answer is great, though for beginners this one https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2007-June/msg00035.html will be in help.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
window.get_property("visible")
#Returns true if the window is visible
```

Comment: I think using the event `VisibilityNotifyEvent` _then_ checking the property `Visible` is better than using the property alone