# How can I use g_idle_add() to get window size?

Tags: c, gtk3, glib

I am trying to get window size after application the window is drawn and full screen I dont want a default 200x200 size. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663212/how-to-know-when-a-gtk-window-is-fully-shown) article suggests using `g_idle_add()`.

```
gpointer data;
int width, height;
void get_sizes()
{
    gtk_window_get_size((GtkWindow*)window, &width, &height);
    printf("Sizes:\t%i × %i\n", width, height);
}
```

I ran `g_idle_add((GSourceFunc)get_sizes, data);` after `gtk_window_present();` The function get_sizes keeps looping endlessly what am i doing wrong?

Comment: [GSourceFunc](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GSourceFunc) must return a boolean. FALSE if the source should be removed. G_SOURCE_CONTINUE and G_SOURCE_REMOVE are more memorable names for the return value

Comment: What's wrong with [`gtk_window_get_size()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-get-size)? You don't need `g_idle_add()` (which just tells the main program loop not to get it immediately, but only when executing the idle function) It more or less just reduces the priority of the call.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica You need `g_idle_add` if for instance, you set a default size on your window coming from a .ui file. The final window size happens last (and depending on your WM, quite a bit later), and you can only get the size after that.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense for grabbing it when there can be dynamic resizing. In the cases where I have used it was basically from a settings dialog or when destroying the final window and writing the last size to a config file for reopening with the last size (no chance of it being dragged around then `:)`

Comment: I used a boolean function like @AlexanderDmitriev suggested and that stops the loop